# Как изменить тригер элемента не задев его стиль? WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

Необходимо настроить тригер в стиле у комбобокса. Использую HandyControl и его комбобокс.
Проблема в том, что когда пытаюсь поменять тригер (и стиль соответственно), то стиль handy control слетает. Нужно что бы и стиль остался и тригер работал.

Comment: Зависит от того, какой именно триггер. Например, можно унаследовать стиль от нужного, и прописать в нем триггеры. Для некоторых триггеров достаточно просто `<Контрол><Контрол.Triggers>...</Контрол.Triggers></Контрол>`. В некоторых случаях триггеры можно заменить поведением, и тогда будет уже `<Контрол ns:Behavior.Click = "...">`. Ну и также, не забывайте про то, что можно вовсе унаследовать контрол целиком и задать ему нужную логику, как и не забывайте про то, что вы можете скачать исходник библиотеки и задать там свой триггер. Вариантов как видите, уйма.

Comment: нужно изменить DataTrigger

Comment: Ну тогда наследуйте стили, условно `<Style .... BaseOn="{StaticResource Оригинал}">триггеры</Style>`.

Comment: Пытался через BaseOn, у Handy Control не могу найти стили.